# Error when default is used within a conditional statement

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, default

The following SQL update statement works when the "default" keyword is being used:

```
UPDATE User SET expDate = DEFAULT WHERE ID=19
```

However, a SYNTAX error (code 1064) is emitted when I add in a condition:

```
UPDATE User SET expDate = IF(expDate > NOW(), DEFAULT, expDate) WHERE ID=19
```

The `DEFAULT` value for `DATETIME` column `expDate` is `"0000-00-00 00:00:00"`

What should be the correct syntax in this case?

**The error:**

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ' expDate) WHERE ID=19' at line 1

Comment: what the error u got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEFAULT` is a keyword. Not a variable. It cannot be used as part of an expression.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

> Each value can be given as an expression, or the keyword DEFAULT to
>   set a column explicitly to its default value.

In your particular case, you might perform *two* updates as part of a transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION
SET @n = NOW()
UPDATE User SET expDate = DEFAULT WHERE ID=19 AND expDate > @n
UPDATE User SET expDate = expDate WHERE ID=19 AND expDate <= @n
COMMIT
```